# How to create IPSec ethernet tunnel between two machines

Tags: networking, security, encryption, ipsec

I've been searching about IPSec. I know that there are two modes: transport layer and ethernet layer. **I'd like to create an ethernet tunnel between two machines using AES and SHA256**, and specify that the traffic through this **tunnel is only for a specifiec subnet**.

On google I can only find informations about cicsco configuration or server configurations. I think it could be made easier for a larger audience, specially now that wifi can be intercepted, it'd be useful to have encryption between local connections through a router which is what I'm trying to do.

I've found this: [Routing LAN traffic through ipsec tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427655/routing-lan-traffic-through-ipsec-tunnel) but is already a bit advanced. For instance, how do I install on both machines, generate and get both of the fingerprints and put them into each other?

Comment: Google has plenty of tutorials for IPsec in Linux or FreeBSD; the topic is advanced in itself.

Comment: Do you really want to try and bridge two LANs? The usual solutions are to bridge a single client or to route between two LANs.